# what is the size of globally declared array in c?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>

char A[];

int main()
{
    printf("%c\n",A[1]);
    return 0;

}
```

I can access any element using index . It never gives error . What is the index of max element i can access for 32 bit machine?

Comment: This compiles? What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc compiler (dev c++)

Comment: @bash.d: GCC compiles this, giving the warning `warning: array ‘A’ assumed to have one element`

Comment: it is an assumption of the array content . What about the size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has size 1. Accesses beyond index 0 (including your code, which accesses `A[1]`) have undefined behavior.

This is 6.9.2 in the C99 standard. `char A[];` is a "tentative definition", which roughly speaking means that if the same translation unit contains a proper definition then it's just a declaration of `A` as an array of char of unknown size. If there's no proper definition then the object is defined anyway as if there were a definition at the end of the translation unit, with a default initializer.

Comment: it talks about the  incomplete type . What about its size ? if we put something A[10000] = 'a' , we still can access this . Am worried about the size .

Comment: @nishantpathak: the only thing that explicitly states the size to be 1 is example 2, which was added to C99 in TC1. I think it's intended to be implied by the text "with an initializer equal to 0". Since `0` isn't a valid initializer for an array, I suppose you're expected to figure out for yourself that in the case of arrays it means `{0}`. The language is the same in C11, so it must make sense to the authors. Just because `A[10000] = 'a'` appears to work doesn't mean your program is correct, it's undefined behavior. Undefined behavior allows for the possibility of appearing to work.

Comment: Note that the size is not known in `main`. You could have `char A[]; int main(void) { … A[1] … } char A[23];`.

Comment: @nishantpathak: The size of `A` is not known until either a definition appears or the end of the source file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : when i try to access sizeof(A)  //  it gives compilation error as invalid application of `sizeof' to incomplete type `({anonymous})' . and without defining how can access its particular index ?

Comment: @nishantpathak: "array of unknown size" is an incomplete type, so you can't use `sizeof` on it. `main` doesn't know its size. However, `main` can still contain code to access a particular index. The exact details can vary by implementation, but I think usually the compiler will emit a fixup that gets filled in by the linker or loader with the address of the start of the array. Then the code in `main` adds 1 to that address and dereferences it. There's no need for the compiler to know the size to do this, but because you've exceeded the bounds of the array you get undefined behavior.

Comment: Adressing `A[10000]`, just like `A[1]` is undefined behavior. If you're lucky, the program crashes immediately. If you're unlucky, you don't see any obvious effect... for now.

Comment: @nishantpathak: In typical implementations, the assembler and the linker provide ways for instructions to refer to the memory address of symbols defined elsewhere. To provide the value of `A[1]`, the compiler will write instructions with the effect of `Load the address of A. Add the size of one element. Load a char from that address.` When the program is linked or loaded, the linker will replace placeholder for `the address of A` with the actual address, so the instructions will work. So the compiler does not need to know where `A` is or how big it is in order to make `A[1]` work.

Comment: @nishantpathak: In contrast, assemblers and linkers provide less support for knowing the sizes of objects associated with symbols. There are generally ways to do this, such as putting a symbol at the end of an object as well as at the beginning, then subtracting the addresses of the two symbols to find the distance between them. However, even if that were done, it would only provide the size at run time, not at compile time. The compiler would not know the size when it is compiling and before it sees the definition.

Comment: Note that if a compiler *wanted* to, it could look ahead to the end of the file (or do an additional pass once it reaches the end of the file) to check whether `A[1]` is in bounds or not. Then it could emit a warning if it's out of bounds, just like gcc emits some warnings for accessing arrays of known size. But the standard is designed to allow for quite simple compilers, so it doesn't require any of that.

Comment: @Medinoc : am agree with all of you guys . But thinks this should be fixed , either by having compile time error of limiting the size of global arrays . Its little bit misleading . Thanks all for your tym.

Comment: @EricPostpischil : so , is it utilizing the complete heap memory before crashing ?

Comment: @nishantpathak: no, it's not using any heap memory. The array has size 1. You access it out of bounds. This access doesn't allocate any memory or change the size of the array. It's pretty much the same as if you'd written `char A[1] = {0}; int main() { int i = 1; printf("%c\n",A[i]); }`

Comment: ok . so the default size is seems to be 1 . am not getting any error may be because accessing any block outside 1 is not causing any problem in my case.

Answer (score 3):

When the declaration `char A[];` appears at file scope, it declares an array. A definition of the array should appear somewhere else. If the definition does not appear in the same file (translation unit), then the behavior is as if a definition appeared with one initializer with value zero, as if you had written `char A[] = { 0 };`.

Code in which the declaration is visible may use the array. However, if the definition of the array is not visible, then the compiler does not know the size of the array. It is the responsibility of the author of the code to use only elements that are actually defined. They must know the size of the array by prior arrangement or by passing some information in the program.

If code uses an element of the array that does not exist, or even calculates an address of an element more than one beyond the end of the array, then the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

`A[1]` will be translated as `*(A+1)` which is basically a memory address . So, `printf` can print whatever is at that memory location. I assume you can keep referencing the array till anything exists at that location (which gives you garbage)[and you are permitted to access that location].

**Edit:** *GCC 4.6.3* gives `warning: array ‘A’ assumed to have one element [enabled by default]`

Answer (score 0):

> I can access any element using index . It never gives error . What is
>   the index of max element i can access for 32 bit machine?

There are a great many things that you *can* do in C which you nevertheless *should not* do. Accessing out of bounds elements of an array is usually one of those things.

When I compile your code using gcc, I get:

```
warning: array ‘A’ assumed to have one element
```

That should be enough to tell you that you should not access any element other than `A[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a pointer, there are no elements in the table. You should not try to index anything.

Comment: This does not declare a pointer; it declares an array that is defined somewhere else. The size of the array is not known in the module with this declaration unless the definition is also visible.

Comment: It is because of the protected mode

Comment: Not explicitly a pointer, but still *(A+n) is valid code (if there's the memory pointed behind the A).